# Salto de linea en formato JSON con Python

Tags: python, json

```
   import json
    
    full_name = input("What is your name? ")
    email = input("Whats your email address ")
    school_id =(input("Enter your school ID "))
    
    filename = 'sing_user.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json_full_name = f'full name : {full_name}' 
        json_email = f'Email address : {email}'
        json_school_id = f'School id : {school_id}'
        json.dump(json_full_name,f_obj)
        json.dump(json_email,f_obj)
        json.dump(json_school_id,f_obj)
```

**Así lo muestra el formato JSON**

```
  "full name : a""Email address : b""School id : 1"
```

Me gustaría poder dar un formato un poco mas Presentable con saltos de linea, no encontrado alguna información acerca de esto si alguien me podría ayudar se lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues solo te hace falta especificar la indentación, por otra parte lo puedes simplificar todo poniendo todos los datos en un diccionario y luego hacer una sola conversión

```py
filename = 'sing_user.json'
with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
    #diccionario que contiene todo
    user = {
        "full name":full_name,
        "Email address":email,
        "School Id": school_id
        }

    json.dump(user,f_obj, indent=4) #especificamos 4 espacios como la indentacion
```

**probamos**

```
What is your name? christian naokiri
Whats your email address none@mail.com
Enter your school ID 0
```

**resultado**

```
{
    "full name": "christian naokiri",
    "Email address": "none@mail.com",
    "School Id": "0"
}
```

Comment: Muchísimos gracias, lo voy a intentar.